# How to update multiple location without clearing GoogleMap

Tags: swift, google-maps, google-maps-markers, markerclusterer

I have load couple of users in map with clustering and now I want to update the users location as per the users new location which I receive from server.

I'm able to do that by clearing the map and load new users data from server but it looks like markers are jumping and it not looks proper.

Is there any way to update the marker locations without clearing the `GoogleMap`?

Here is the link of my question : [Google Map with Cluster and Custom view marker lagging too much while zoomIn and zoomOut](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57040146/google-map-with-cluster-and-custom-view-marker-lagging-too-much-while-zoomin-and)

## Reference Screen

[image]

if some one is moved from his location then how can I update his/her location once I receive updated data from server. (Without clearing the map)

## My Code

```
func setMarkers() {
        for i in 0..<SharedData.sharedInstance.allFriends.count {
            let marker = GMSMarker()
            let friend = SharedData.sharedInstance.allFriends[i]
            marker.position = CLLocationCoordinate2D.init(latitude: friend.user_details.latitude , longitude: friend.user_details.longitude)
            marker.accessibilityHint = String(i)
            marker.icon = #imageLiteral(resourceName: "trans")
            marker.tracksViewChanges = true
            marker.map = mapView

            arrMarkers.append(marker)
            self.generatePOIItems(String(format: "%d", i), position: marker.position, icon: nil, friend: friend, userIndex: i)
        }
        clusterManager.cluster()
        clusterManager.setDelegate(self, mapDelegate: self)
    }

    func updateMarkers() {
        for i in 0..<arrMarkers.count {
            let marker = arrMarkers[i]
            let friend = SharedData.sharedInstance.allFriends[i]
            marker.position = CLLocationCoordinate2D.init(latitude: friend.user_details.latitude , longitude: friend.user_details.longitude)
            marker.accessibilityHint = String(i)
            marker.icon = #imageLiteral(resourceName: "trans")
            marker.tracksViewChanges = true
            marker.map = mapView
        }
        self.defaultCamera(latitude: SharedData.sharedInstance.userLocation.coordinate.latitude, longitude: SharedData.sharedInstance.userLocation.coordinate.longitude)
    }
```

**EDIT**

```
func generatePOIItems(_ accessibilityLabel: String, position: CLLocationCoordinate2D, icon: UIImage?, friend: WallBeeppClass, userIndex: Int) {
        let name = "Item \(accessibilityLabel)"
        let item = POIItem(position: CLLocationCoordinate2DMake(position.latitude, position.longitude), name: name, friend: friend, userIndex: userIndex)
        clusterManager.add(item)
    }


func updateMarkers() {
        for i in 0..<arrMarkers.count {
            let marker = arrMarkers[i]
            let friend = SharedData.sharedInstance.allFriends[i]

            CATransaction.begin()
            CATransaction.setAnimationDuration(1.0)
            marker.position = CLLocationCoordinate2D.init(latitude: friend.user_details.latitude , longitude: friend.user_details.longitude)
            CATransaction.commit()
        }
    }
```

**EDIT 1**

If I change some users location from backend and when I got users new location then I update the marker position using above code but the issue is that new location users are still located at old location. and if I clear & redraw the users data then it works fine.

**EDIT 2**

```
func renderer(_ renderer: GMUClusterRenderer, willRenderMarker marker: GMSMarker) {
        marker.groundAnchor = CGPoint(x: 0.1, y: 0.45)
        if let markerData = (marker.userData as? POIItem) {
            let infoWindow = Bundle.main.loadNibNamed("InitialMapInfoView", owner: self, options: nil)?.first as! InitialMapInfoView
            infoWindow.imgUser.sd_setImage(with: URL(string: markerData.friend.user_details.user_photo_small), placeholderImage: #imageLiteral(resourceName: "User_profile"), options: .highPriority, completed: nil)

            if !markerData.friend.user_details.isUserOnline {
                infoWindow.imgCar.image = UIImage.init(named: "small_inactive_" + markerData.friend.user_details.car_personality_name)
            }
            else {
                infoWindow.imgCar.image = UIImage.init(named: "small_" + markerData.friend.user_details.car_personality_name)
            }

            if markerData.friend.user_details.user_id == 88 {
                print("Will Rendrer Marker: \(markerData.friend.user_details.latitude)")
                print("Will Rendrer Marker: \(markerData.friend.user_details.longitude)")
            }

            infoWindow.lblName.text = markerData.friend.user_details.name
            infoWindow.btnImgVW.tag = markerData.userIndex
            infoWindow.btnImgVW.addTarget(self, action: #selector(btnUserTapped(_:)), for: .touchUpInside)
            marker.accessibilityHint = String(markerData.userIndex)
            marker.iconView = infoWindow
            marker.tracksViewChanges = false
        }
```

Please guide me to do this.

Comment: Any code snippet to visualise the current state of the application and where in the code you facing this issue?

Comment: you can subclass GMSMarker, add id of your objects, then get markers by object id you got from server and update position

Comment: @rags2riches, I have added reference screen and comment

Comment: @AlexandrKolesnik, currently I have stored all markers in GMSMarker type array and I already updated the user new lat long. please review my added code

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you can subclass GMSMarker, add id of your objects, then get markers by object id you got from server and update position. Here is some code to explain what I mean

```
    class MyMarker: GMSMarker {

         var id: String? = nil

    }
```

add id to your marker

```
func setMarkers() {

        let marker = MyMarker()
        let friend = SharedData.sharedInstance.allFriends[I]
        marker.id = friend.id
```

than update by id

```
for friend in SharedData.sharedInstance.allFriends {
        guard
            let marker = array.first { $0.id == friend.id }
        else { contiunue }
        marker.position = CLLocationCoordinate2D.init(latitude: friend.user_details.latitude , longitude: friend.user_details.longitude)
    }
```

don't add marker to map again, just change it's position

Comment: new coordinated successfully updated  but when I zoning/ zoomOut the map user shows me at the same position. User needs to be move to new location but it stay at the old location

Comment: what are your actions when camera zoomIn/zoomOut, I don't see your code, but try to update self.generatePOIItems(your cluster) when you update marker positions

Comment: if I try generatePOIItems then it will adds new marker over old one.

Comment: remove items from cluster before adding

Comment: Clearing the cluster idea before adding will work but it consume lots of memory. If I got new data from servers 5 times then memory hike from 90MB to 300MB. Is there any alternate solution?

Comment: mapView.clear() but I think the problem is not with map, somewhere memory leak, by the way, marker position is changing with animation by default

Comment: Please review my updated question. When `willRenderMarker` method called GMSMarker user data gives me old Coordinates so please help me to update the marker data in my `updateMarkers()` delegate.

Comment: where should I look?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/197035/discussion-between-kuldeep-and-alexandr-kolesnik).

Comment: can you add link on GitHub or smth?

Comment: will you please look into this : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57231345/custom-markers-disappear-on-zoomin-the-map-and-appear-on-zoomout-the-map-with-cl