# Custom Markers disappear on zoomin the map and appear on zoomout the map with Clustering

Tags: swift, google-maps, google-maps-sdk-ios, markerclusterer

I have load multiple pins in GoogleMap with clustering and below is my code.

Link : https://github.com/googlemaps/google-maps-ios-utils/issues/235

```
func initializeClusterItems() {
    let iconGenerator = GMUDefaultClusterIconGenerator()
    let algorithm = GMUNonHierarchicalDistanceBasedAlgorithm()
    let renderer = GMUDefaultClusterRenderer(mapView: mapView, clusterIconGenerator: iconGenerator)
    renderer.delegate = self
    clusterManager = GMUClusterManager(map: mapView, algorithm: algorithm, renderer: renderer)
}

func renderer(_ renderer: GMUClusterRenderer, willRenderMarker marker: GMSMarker) {
    marker.groundAnchor = CGPoint(x: 0.1, y: 0.45)
    if let markerData = (marker.userData as? POIItem) {
        let infoWindow = Bundle.main.loadNibNamed("InitialMapInfoView", owner: self, options: nil)?.first as! InitialMapInfoView
        infoWindow.imgUser.sd_setImage(with: URL(string: markerData.friend.user_details.user_photo_small), placeholderImage: #imageLiteral(resourceName: "User_profile"), options: .highPriority, completed: nil)

        if let objCurrentMarker = SharedData.sharedInstance.allFriends.first(where: {$0.user_details.user_id == markerData.friend.user_details.user_id}) {
            print("Latitude: \(markerData.position.latitude)")
            print("Longitude: \(markerData.position.longitude)")

            print(objCurrentMarker.user_details.screen_name)

            print("Update Latitude: \(objCurrentMarker.user_details.latitude)")
            print("Update Longitude: \(objCurrentMarker.user_details.longitude)")

            markerData.position = CLLocationCoordinate2D.init(latitude: objCurrentMarker.user_details.latitude, longitude: objCurrentMarker.user_details.longitude)
            markerData.friend.user_details.isUserOnline = objCurrentMarker.user_details.isUserOnline
        }

        if !markerData.friend.user_details.isUserOnline {
            infoWindow.imgCar.image = UIImage.init(named: "small_inactive_" + markerData.friend.user_details.car_personality_name)
        }
        else {
            infoWindow.imgCar.image = UIImage.init(named: "small_" + markerData.friend.user_details.car_personality_name)
        }

        infoWindow.lblName.text = markerData.friend.user_details.name
        infoWindow.btnImgVW.tag = markerData.userIndex
        infoWindow.btnImgVW.addTarget(self, action: #selector(btnUserTapped(_:)), for: .touchUpInside)
        marker.accessibilityHint = String(markerData.userIndex)
        marker.iconView = infoWindow
        marker.tracksViewChanges = false
    }
}

func setMarkers() {
    arrMarkers.removeAll()
    for i in 0..<SharedData.sharedInstance.allFriends.count {
        let marker = MyMarker()
        let friend = SharedData.sharedInstance.allFriends[i]
        marker.id = friend.user_details.user_id
        marker.position = CLLocationCoordinate2D.init(latitude: friend.user_details.latitude , longitude: friend.user_details.longitude)
        marker.accessibilityHint = String(i)

        marker.icon = #imageLiteral(resourceName: "trans")
        marker.tracksViewChanges = true
        marker.map = mapView

        arrMarkers.append(marker)
        self.generatePOIItems(String(format: "%d", i), position: marker.position, icon: nil, friend: friend, userIndex: i)
    }
    clusterManager.cluster()
    clusterManager.setDelegate(self, mapDelegate: self)
}

func updateMarkers() {
    clusterManager.cluster()
}

func generatePOIItems(_ accessibilityLabel: String, position: CLLocationCoordinate2D, icon: UIImage?, friend: WallBeeppClass, userIndex: Int) {
    let name = "Item \(accessibilityLabel)"
    let item = POIItem(position: CLLocationCoordinate2DMake(position.latitude, position.longitude), name: name, friend: friend, userIndex: userIndex)
    clusterManager.add(item)
}

class POIItem: NSObject, GMUClusterItem {
    var position: CLLocationCoordinate2D
    var name: String!
    var friend: WallBeeppClass!
    var userIndex: Int!

    init(position: CLLocationCoordinate2D, name: String, friend: WallBeeppClass, userIndex: Int) {
        self.position = position
        self.name = name
        self.friend = friend
        self.userIndex = userIndex
    }
}
```

I want to update the users latitude & longitude inside clusterManagerItems.

I tried the below line to change location data inside `func renderer(_ renderer: GMUClusterRenderer, willRenderMarker marker: GMSMarker){}` but app crashing with this error

> 'All items should be mapped to a distance'

```
markerData.position = CLLocationCoordinate2D.init(latitude: objCurrentMarker.user_details.latitude, longitude: objCurrentMarker.user_details.longitude)
```

If I add below line then it works but when I zoomIn/ZoomOut the map. clusterManager item load at old position and then it load to new position.

```
marker.position = CLLocationCoordinate2D.init(latitude: objCurrentMarker.user_details.latitude, longitude: objCurrentMarker.user_details.longitude)
```

A you can see, I printed `markerData.friend.user_details.latitude` details which contains old coordinats of user and I also printed user's latest data `objCurrentMarker.user_details.latitude` which contains the latest coordinates.

## EDIT1

I'm able to update the already added `GMUClusterItem` but the issue is that when i call `clusterManager.cluster()` again when I receive new data from server then `GMUClusterItem` is gone when I zoomin the map and come again on map when zoomout the Map.

## EDIT 2

**Reference Video Link**

https://gofile.io/?c=8z0vE5

## EDIT 3

Custom Marker disappear because of the below code. when I comment below code then marker wasn't disappear from map.

```
CATransaction.begin()
CATransaction.setAnimationDuration(1.0)
marker.position = CLLocationCoordinate2D.init(latitude: objCurrentMarker.user_details.latitude, longitude: objCurrentMarker.user_details.longitude)
CATransaction.commit()
```

Please guide me how to update already added Clustermanager item?

Thanks in advance

Comment: are you sure you need all that code in willRender func? my func is more simpler func renderer(_ renderer: GMUClusterRenderer, willRenderMarker marker: GMSMarker) {
        guard let infoMarker = (marker.userData as? POIItem)?.marker
            else {
                return
        }
        marker.iconView = infoMarker.iconView
    }

Comment: yes I need to keep this code inside willRender because initially if I load all markers on map then map is lagging too much. the reason to keep this code in willRender is it will load the marker data once clustering expand. that way the map not lagging

Comment: you are setting all markers in setMarkers func

Comment: @AlexandrKolesnik, will you please look into this demo and let me know where I'm doing mistake so that marker is gone while zoomin the map

Comment: I tried your code nothing disappearing, I added you code with problem             CATransaction.begin()
            CATransaction.setAnimationDuration(1.0)
            marker.position = markerData.position
            CATransaction.commit() and it is still works

Comment: @AlexandrKolesnik Theres 1 user Chris01 at simulator FREEWAY DRIVE which is continuously moving. please move MapView to that location & try to zoomin & zoomOut that user CHRIS01

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/197267/discussion-between-alexandr-kolesnik-and-kuldeep).

Answer (score 3):

One thing that worked for me was to disable animations at the renderer level, i.e., GMUClusterRenderer.animatesClusters = false

Comment: it looks like this actually really works in my swiftUI setup... 
Thanks a lot @PauloTaylor